# Jenkins - bash: aws: command not found but runs fine from terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh

In Build Step, I've added **Send files or execute command over SSh** -> SSH Publishers -> Exec command, I'm trying to run aws command to copy file from ec2 to s3. The same command runs fine when I execute it over the terminal, but via jenkins it simply returns:
**bash: aws: command not found**

The command is
 `cd ~/.local/bin/ && aws s3 cp /home/ec2-user/lambda_test/lambda_function.zip s3://temp-airflow-us/lambda_function.zip`

Comment: What about `cd ~/.local/bin/ && ./aws s3 cp /home/ec2-user/lambda_test/lambda_function.zip s3://temp-airflow-us/lambda_function.zip`

Comment: yes, this worked. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use the following command:

```
cd ~/.local/bin/ && ./aws s3 cp /home/ec2-user/lambda_test/lambda_function.zip s3://temp-airflow-us/lambda_function.zip
```

since `aws` is not available in `PATH` env variable.

Answer (score 0):

`command not found` indicates that the aws utility is not on $PATH for the jenkins user.

To confirm, `sudo su -l jenkins` and then issue the command `which aws` - this will most likely return no results.

You have two options:

1. use the full path (likely `/usr/local/bin/aws`)
2. add `/usr/local/bin` to the jenkins user's $PATH

Answer (score 0):

I need my Makefile to work in both Linux and Windows so the accepted answer is not an option for me.

I diagnosed the problem by adding the following to the top of my build script:

```
whoami
which aws
env|grep PATH
```

This returned:

```
root
which: no aws in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Bizarrely, the path does not include `/usr/local/bin`, even though the interactive shell on the Jenkins host includes it. The fix is simple enough, create a symlink on the Jenkins host:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/aws /bin/aws
```

Now the `aws` command can be found by scripts running in Jenkins (in `/bin`).